# Dynamic embedding of flash video

Tags: content-editor-web-part, connected-web-parts, video, page-viewer-web-part

I can successfully hard code an embed path in a Content Editor WebPart(CEWP) or link a CEWP to a text file that has the embed path, but this is hard coded because the CEWP is not connectable and I would prefer it to be fed from a list.

I have set up 2 columns in my list, one with the Image URL (video thumbnail) and another for the Video URL. Using the Connectable Page Viewer web Part, I am able to pull the URLs from the into an embed path, but this does not display the video even though the output is the same as hard coding the embed Path.

Any ideas on how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I would try useing jQuery/COM to get URLs from list dynamically and hardcode this inside CEWP